# Converting input string to category

Tags: java, android

I've been making new screen to add category from user input, but how can I convert that input string to category? The `newEntry` needs to be converted.

```
//Code for button:

button_insert_cat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                try{
                    String newEntry = textBoxInsert.getText().toString();
                    if (textBoxInsert.length() != 0) {
                        QuizDbHelper.getInstance(AddCategory.this).addCategory(newEntry);
                        toastMessage("Added successfully!");
                        textBoxInsert.setText("");
                    } else {
                        toastMessage("You must put something in the text field!");
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
```

Method I'm trying to call:

```
public void addCategory(Category category) {
        db = getWritableDatabase();
        insertCategory(category);
    }
```

Comment: How would we know when we don't know what `Category` is? It might have a constructor taking a `String` argument, or it might have a `static` method taking a `String` argument, but since we don't know the methods of `Category`, we certainly cannot help you.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, Category is class with with 2 parametars int id, and string name, and there is param constructor for it:
 public Category(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

And one toString:
public String toString() {
        return getName();
    }

Answer (score 0):

```
QuizDbHelper.getInstance(AddCategory.this).addCategory(new Category(newEntry));
```

Comment: Thanks mate, you saved me! So simple, but when u are still newbie, everything seems "hard" :)

Comment: I did it :) Thanks one more time! :)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.